# ERROR Dist-upgrade failed when upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: apt, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 yet when running the `sudo do-release-upgrade` I get the error message:

```
Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

This was likely caused by:
Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and try the upgrade again.

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.
```

I checked `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log` which contains the following message:

```
ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'Broken packages after upgrade: evolution-data-server, gnome-control-center, libgirepository-1.0-1, ubuntu-desktop'
```

I'm not familiar with these packages and they look necessary. Is it safe to run `ppa-purge` or `sudo apt remove` on them? How should I proceed from here?

Comment: The `evolution-data-server` package is only essential if you want/need to use the GNOME desktop, as it's a backend server used by it, it's **not** part of the GNOME MUA `evolution`.  If your packages are from 3rd party repositories, you should revert to the Ubuntu repository packages and not just remove them (if you want those features/functions available when you get to *jammy*)

Comment: How do I revert them?

Comment: `ppa-purge` is usually used for that purpose, https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed maybe helpful, but I've not used that tool in (>5) years so I'd prefer not to advise.  If I've made many package changes from 3rd party, I usually opt to non-destructively re-install (ie. *Upgrade via re-install*)